# How to change write permissions to a usb

Tags: debian, usb

I just installed debian 9 stable and I need to remove the read only permission from my usb. I used the usb to install the os and after the setting changed itself

Comment: If applicable, try `sudo remount -rw /dev/sdc1`, change `/dev/sdc1` to what corresponds to your USB device.

Answer (score 1):

The debian installer uses the ISO9660 filesystem which is immutable, you will need to reformat your USB drive if you want to use it for general file storage.

eg: in nautilus right-click the drive and follow the prompts